# Moving system from ESXi to Hyper-V

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, hypervisor, conversion

I have a problem with moving a system from ESXi to Hyper-V.

The system on ESXi has got 100GB allocated space on HDD. The system is made from an image file(size about 6GB). The machine hosting Hyper-V has about 110GB free space. Is there any way to convert the VM?
Or another question: The system running on ESXi has about 90GB free space. Is there a way to make a backup file from that system with size about 10GB? It would be easier to handle and convert from vmdk to vhd on a third machine.

Sorry for my bad English,
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: possibly http://www.5nine.com/vmware-hyper-v-v2v-conversion-free.aspx or http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34591 will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter. It can even install as a plug-in in vSphere.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967435.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Physical to Virtual tools to do a Virtual to Virtual conversion between two different virtualization platforms.  [Microsoft has a tool for that](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764232.aspx).

To answer the second question, you should be able to copy the VM files off the ESXi server using SCP - you'll need to [enable SSH on the ESXi server](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004746) if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfectly working gzip in the ESXi console, you could use that to make a backup, at least if most of the space has never been allocated to files. You could force zeroing by creating a large empty file within the VM - but that can lower your thin provisioning efficiency later if you want to go that way since some filesystems will then allocate small but inconveniently placed structures...

Is there any NFS-capable NAS with some free space at hand? ESXi speaks fluent NFS, so you can set up some shared scratch space between both machines...